# Anaconda equivalent of 'Git Bash Here' Right-Click Menu

Tags: bash, operating-system, anaconda, right-click, cd

I'm looking to add an Anaconda equivalent of the Git Bash Right-Click menu, 'Git Bash Here' where Git Bash would open and `cd` to the current folder as shown here:
[Right-Click Menu and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrjDq.png)

I know that programs can be added to the right click menu through the Registry Editor but I could not find how to go further with Anaconda to have it `cd` to the folder also.

Help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you hold Shift+Right Click, an option to open a command prompt here is shown. Assuming you put Anaconda's python (and other binaries) onto your path, that should work

Comment: @darthbith Thanks for your answer and it serves most purposes but things like conda environments (`activate` and `deactivate`) do not work in the Powershell. I looked up a bit and things such as [this](https://github.com/Liquidmantis/PSCondaEnvs) can be done but I thought maybe there could be a straight forward way of opening anaconda with the current directory.

Comment: IIRC you can change the default so that the regular CMD prompt opens, instead of powershell

Comment: @darthbith thanks for the suggestion, while I was looking that up, I found that you can open CMD in any folder by typing `CMD` in the address bar. `conda env` works here. Thanks again.